# Beginning bread boarding question

Tags: prototyping

[image: Photo of circuit board]

Is the diagonal 10k too close? Am I good?

Comment: It's a good idea to keep everything at 90 degree angles until you're more experienced. Just as a general tip.

Comment: Well, you could drop the left side of the wonky resistor down two holes and have the wire link start one hole higher. I don't like having a link running over the top like that anyway personally, and since it appears to be linking two pins on opposite sides of the IC, I'd just connect them on the underside. But it's all somewhat a matter of taste.

Comment: @IanBland, no the point is that you could not mount the resistor parallel to the IC, because the body is more than 200 mil long.  Look at the other two - they only just fit between holes spaced 300 mil.  To mount it parallel to the IC, you'd have to go over an additional row to get the 300 mil, and then come back on the underside of the board, or else extend it in the 3rd dimension away from the board.

Comment: It'd probably cram into 2 holes, but the proper alternative would be to go out to the next row as you say, which would be a neater and mechanically stronger result. This sort of construction doesn't do compact layouts, after all. Using an additional track for this purpose is normal procedure with this kind of layout.

Comment: Your board may already have copper pads on each hole. Based on the transparency of the board im not sure. So if yours dosen't, getting a board with copper pad per hole will make your life much easier

Answer (score 2):

Since you are dealing with low voltage levels, with no risk of arcing, you are fine with that resistor, at the moment. The exposed parts of the diagonal resistor leads are not close to exposed parts of either the purple wire or the nearby "vertical" 10k resistor.